# Can I use generic classes with generic methods?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Currently I use generics like so

```
public class A<T> where T : B {
    public T Foo {get; set; }
}


public class A1 : A<B1>{

}

public class A2 : A<B2> {

}

public class B {

}

public class B1 : B {
    // Specific data here
}

public class B2 : B {
    // Specific data here
}
```

Is it possible to combine multiple layers of generics?

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
public class A<T> where T : B<C<D>> {
    public T Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Where B, C and D are all generics like class A

Comment: Change your interface name, please. It makes it more confusing when names collide.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Maybe you should try to be more clear here. That the generic Type of a method is a generic in itself should make no difference. Is your problem automapper here that you don't want to create mappings for all possible types?

Comment: All of this because of lazy loading? What if you just prevent lazy loading? I would think you are on  Entity Framework 6.x or even earlier.

Comment: I feel for your next employer as well. Maybe your documentation is all explanatory, but judging by your question, I seriously doubt it. I was about to vote to close, but only didn't, in the hope that you might explain what you really want to do.

Comment: Standard convention has interface names beginning with I. It is not a rule, but is almost universally accepted. It makes code so much easier to read.

Comment: I have removed several part of the post in an attempt to better convey what I am trying to accomplish. This is something I was toying around with and merely wanted to see what was possible. Not too sure what my employer has to do with this. I used A,B,C and D because it was easy for this example. If it is that incomprehensible I can change it something you all could understand.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Automapper?

Comment: @Zapcrack Generally, the names `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `qux` are preferred instead of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` because they work better with how the human brain handles language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable - similarly in cryptography and infosec "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", etc are used instead of "PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", etc.